# Find out which html form was submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Assume I have many html forms in a website. I need to find out which html form was submitted.

```
$("form").submit(function(event){ }
```

Using the function above, can i find out which form was submitted?

Comment: Give them ID's or something to make them unique.

Comment: use ID for forms.

Comment: You can check the attributes assigned to the form-tag using `$(this).attr()` like its `id`.

Comment: I'm nort sure though I think always the first form in the array wil be submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign an identifiable attribute to the form and use `event.target` to access that attribute.

In this case, I've assigned `name` to each form and printed the name on the console when the form is submitted.

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<form name="form2">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<form name="form3">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is recommended to use ID, you can do without it. your event.target provides the reference for the form.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var a = $(event.target).children("input[type='text']").val();
console.log(a);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uhxywkr/1/)

Thanks @31piy for reminding about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into link below to identify submission of different forms.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Form1").submit(function(event) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#Form2").submit(function(event) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#other").click(function() {
    $("#Form1").submit();
  });

  $("#other2").click(function() {
    $("#Form2").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="Form1" action="destination.html">
      <input type="text" value="Hello there">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
      <div id="other">
        Click to trigger the handler for first form
      </div>
    </form>


    <form id="Form2" action="destination.html">
      <input type="text" value="Hello there">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
      <div id="other2">
        Click to trigger the handler for second form
      </div>
    </form>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I usually submit every form to a different route handler. This way I manage to keep some basic principles (Single responsibility principle). Otherwise, you risk your code becoming too complicated to read.

If you insist on having the same route and then differentiate in the backend, I believe the other answers will give you answer your question.